# bigquery backup all view definitions

Tags: google-bigquery, view, backup

I am working with bigquery, and there have been a few hundred views created.  Most of these are not used and should be deleted. However, there is a chance that some are used and I cannot just blindly delete all.  Therefore, I need to backup all view definitions somehow before deleting them.

Does anyone know of a good way? I am not trying to save the data, just the view definition queries and their names.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 8):

Building off the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814065/bigquery-backup-all-view-definitions/48814236#48814236), you can automate the backing up of **all** views by parsing the output of `bq` with `jq`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DATASETS=$(bq  ls --format=sparse | tail -n+3)
for d in $DATASETS; do
  TABLES=$(bq ls --format=prettyjson "$d" | jq '.[] | "\(.id), \(.type)"')
  IFS=$'\n'
  for table in $TABLES; do
    [[ ! "$table" == *VIEW* ]] && continue
    view=$(echo "$table" | sed -e 's/"//g' | cut -d , -f 1)
    query=$(bq show --format=prettyjson "$view" | jq -r '.view.query')
    echo -e "$query" > "$view.sql"
  done
done
```

Comment: If using ZSH - it does not split words by default, so additional setopt sh_word_split is needed

Answer (score 5):

**Part 1.**

Issue the `bq ls` command. The `--format` flag can be used to control the output. If you are listing views in a project other than your default project, add the project ID to the dataset in the following format: `[PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET]`.

```
bq ls --format=pretty [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET]
```

Where:

`[PROJECT_ID]` is your project ID.
`[DATASET]` is the name of the dataset.

When you run the command, the Type field displays either `TABLE` or `VIEW`. For example:

```
+-------------------------+-------+----------------------+-------------------+
|         tableId         | Type  |        Labels        | Time Partitioning |
+-------------------------+-------+----------------------+-------------------+
| mytable                 | TABLE | department:shipping  |                   |
| myview                  | VIEW  |                      |                   |
+-------------------------+-------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

**Part 2.**

Issue the `bq show` command. The `--format` flag can be used to control the output. If you are getting information about a view in a project other than your default project, add the project ID to the dataset in the following format: `[PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET]`. To write the view properties to a file, add `> [PATH_TO_FILE]` to the command.

```
bq show --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[VIEW] > [PATH_TO_FILE]
```

Where:

`[PROJECT_ID]` is your project ID.
`[DATASET]` is the name of the dataset.
`[VIEW]` is the name of the view.
`[PATH_TO_FILE]` is the path to the output file on your local machine.

Examples:

Enter the following command to display information about myview in mydataset. mydataset is in your default project.

```
bq show --format=prettyjson mydataset.myview
```

Enter the following command to display information about `myview` in `mydataset`. mydataset is in myotherproject, not your default project. The view properties are written to a local file — `/tmp/myview.json`.

```
bq show --format=prettyjson myotherproject:mydataset.myview > /tmp/myview.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [bqup](https://github.com/thinkingmachines/bqup), which is a python script that some colleagues and I have been using to regularly back up BigQuery views and table schemata.

Comment: No longer installable via "pip bqup", and also git cloning and attempting to install fails

Comment: @LucasZamboulis It should be `pip install bqup`. Exactly what error were you encountering?

Comment: my bad, needed to upgarde  pip with `pip install --upgrade pip` first.